# defining typed constant numbers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macros, constants, unsigned

In C/C++, is there a difference between saying `(1U)` vs. `((unsigned int)1)` ? I prefer the second one, but I am concerned that the second one may be type-cast at run time (i.e. extra cpu cycles), whereas the first one gets the correct type at compilation. Thanks.

Comment: Even if it makes any difference, it would be optimized at compile-time by just about every modern compiler.

Comment: I'm sure there are some technical differences, but no practical ones.

Comment: I am curios what instructions you think are used to covert int(1) to unsigned int(1).

Answer (score 5):

They're not equivalent. `1U` is valid in `#if` preprocessing directives. `(unsigned int)1` is a syntax error at the preprocessor level. You could however make it `(unsigned)+1` and it would be valid in the preprocessor, but only because of an obscure rule few people know..

Comment: 'Pre-processor numbers' are plain weird!  ISO/IEC 9899:1999, §6.4.8 _Preprocessing numbers_ defines the syntax as (pipes indicating newlines):  `pp-number: digit | . digit | pp-number digit | pp-number identifier-nondigit | pp-number e sign | pp-number E sign | pp-number p sign | pp-number P sign | pp-number .`

That means a _pp-number_ can contain all sorts of alpha characters.

The `(unsigned)` is (probably) not defined as a number, so it gets translated to 0, and `(0)+1` is valid as an integer - though probably not as an unsigned value despite appearances to the contrary.

Comment: Good point about it not being unsigned. How does signedness work at the PP level anyway? All arithmetic takes place as if in a max-size integer type, but what about signed/unsigned comparison issues, overflow/wrapping of huge values, etc.?

Comment: Looking at §6.10.1 _Conditional inclusion_, ¶3: _After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers are replaced with the pp-number
0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens
compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of
6.6, except that all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have
the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` defined
in the header `<stdint.h>`._

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it right.
(1U) I suspect will be recognised by the compiler's lexical analysis as "unsigned" while (unsigned int)1 will be a runtime operation.
As the comments say, chances are it will be optimised out for you anyway.

As a general rule, don't try to out think the compiler. Do what looks most readable to you and worry about performance optimization once it becomes clear you have a problem.
I can guarantee* this will never actually cause you a problem.

*guarantee void on days ending with a Y.

Comment: The chances of `(unsigned int)1` being a runtime operation are essentially nil, even in the least optimizing of non-optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 0):

11 characters. Otherwise, they are equivalent.