# How use #define statement

Tags: c, casting

I often use #define statement. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SAMPLENO 100

int main()
{
    uint8_t num_of_samples;
    //some code
    if(num_of_samples == SAMPLENO)
    {
        //some code
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Recently, I have heard that, #define statement should be used with casting type. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SAMPLENO ((uint8_t)100)

int main()
{
    uint8_t num_of_samples;
    //some code
    if(num_of_samples == SAMPLENO)
    {
        //some code
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is following, Is casting type necessary?

Comment: Choose a language. There is no such thing as C/C++. You won't use a macro at all in C++ for this.

Comment: Why do you use a macro at all?

Comment: Where have you header _"that, #define statement should be used with casting type."_?

Comment: Add the verbatim error text into your question please.

Comment: @ckruczek - How did you know to choose C for the OP?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9170683/1025391

Comment: @StoryTeller. I didn't. I just removed the tags and kept the original tags. And to be frankly, the code he is showing looks pretty C-ish.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question as asked .... In rough terms I would recommend against macros AT ALL in your code.  And I would avoid using type explicit conversions (aka type casts) wherever possible - whether in macros or not.

To answer in more detail .....

The trick is to understand the code that is output by the preprocessing phase in circumstances where your macro is used.   If that code requires a type conversion, then it may make sense for the macro to supply it.

For example, ignoring the content of standard headers, the output from the preprocessor given your first code sample would be something like

```
int main()
{
     uint8_t num_of_samples;
     //some code
     if(num_of_samples == 100)
     {
         //some code
     }

     return 0;
}
```

So, to answer your question, you would need to decide if the literal `100` should be converted to `uint8_t` in this context.    Go through the same consideration for all reasonable ways in which your macro might be used.

In this case, the type conversion is probably not necessary.  At most, it may suppress a compiler warning - which is a valid consideration in some projects but not others.   It does not change the behaviour of the code, as observed by a user of your program.

Bear in mind that it is often preferable to avoid type conversions in real-world code, because they can cause the compiler to accept code that would otherwise be rejected (i.e. result in a failed compilation).    Introducing a type conversion via a macro will be highly dangerous in such cases, unless you can confirm all the possible use cases are valid.

As others have said in comments, it is probably a better practice to find some technique other than macros (which makes your question about using a type conversion in a macro a bit academic).   Yes, macros have their uses - but there are better alternatives, in both C and C++ in many cases.   Including yours.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the defined constant matters, then you should use a cast. This is something that has to be considered on case-by-case basis depending on how the define is used.

In the example you posted, the cast is pointless. In case either or both operands of the `==` operator are so-called "small integer types", which they are in this case, they are implicitly type converted to type `int`. Thus your code is 100% equivalent to

```
if((int)num_of_samples == (int)SAMPLENO)
```

and the `(uint8_t)100` cast was completely pointless.